# android unlocker for myself

Tags: android

How can I do a unlocker ad for myself?

I have second application and what I want is that ask user an offer if user install my second application I will give him some bonus..

but I dont know how to open Market Installing Screen in my application and how to know if he installed or not?

```
public void GetFreeBonus(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Bonus.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public class Bonus extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
        setContentView(R.layout.bonus);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the market from your app, [check out this section in the developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent), and to test to see if an application is installed, [take a look here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/detect-if-an-app-is-installed). (You would check this on the onResume once the user comes back from installing the app).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is asking. The first link tells you how to open the Android Market page for a specified app, and the second link can help you detect if a specified app was installed (via Android Market, or any other method).